# pass wget output (streamed shell script) to bash, but with extra arguments

Tags: bash, wget

I'd like to download the specific file via `wget`, pass it as a `bash` script and in one shot also provide arguments for it.

In my case, the script is stored at: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh`

I've tried:

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh | bash
```

but it ends with:

```
Error: you need to provide a host and port to test.
Usage:
    bash host:port [-s] [-t timeout] [-- command args]
    -h HOST | --host=HOST       Host or IP under test
    -p PORT | --port=PORT       TCP port under test
                            Alternatively, you specify the host and port as host:port
    -s | --strict               Only execute subcommand if the test succeeds
    -q | --quiet                Don't output any status messages
    -t TIMEOUT | --timeout=TIMEOUT
                            Timeout in seconds, zero for no timeout
    -- COMMAND ARGS             Execute command with args after the test finishes
```

as I'd also need to pass arguments to this `bash` script (*hostname* and *port* to check in my specific case), namely I'd need to run something like:

```
wait-for-it.sh localhost:8181
```

**UPDATE:**
I'd love to have the solution without local save (=> pipe to `bash` only please)

Comment: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh && bash wait-for-it.sh localhost:8181`

Comment: @Leon OK, downloading and executing works, but I prefer to do it without local save

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a script that's *not* recursive, it's easy:

```
 # pipe source code to `bash`, run code with args *foo* and *bar*
 <stream with source code> | bash -s - foo bar
```

But the script `wait-for-it.sh` contains `$0`, and is somewhat recursive, (it calls itself), and which makes it incompatible with streaming, since:

1. the stream doesn't have a filename where random access seeks work,
2. there's no way to change `$0` to the name of the stream.

A `bash` piping function gets around that:

```
strm2fnct(){ 
s=${1:-self$$}
sed "1i $s"'() {
s/\$0/'"$s"'/
/timeout/{s/'"$s"'[^&]*/bash -c "&" /};
$a \} ; export -f '"$s; $s"' "$@"'
}
```

Usage for this Q:

```
f='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh'
wget -O - "$f" | strm2fnct ${f##*/} | bash -s - 'localhost:8181'
```

Output:

```
--2017-05-21 21:21:49--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 151.101.36.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.36.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4070 (4.0K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-   100%[===========================================>]   3.97K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

2017-05-21 21:21:50 (29.8 KB/s) - written to stdout [4070/4070]

wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for localhost:8181
wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for localhost:8181
```

---

**Method.**

Although `bash` doesn't save streaming data, it remembers functions.   Therefore `strm2fnct`:

- wraps the entire stream (comments and all) inside of an *ad hoc*
  shell function; example:

  ```
  strm2fnct <<< "echo hello world"
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  self6196() {
  echo hello world
  } ; export -f self6196; self6196 "$@"
  ```
- this *ad hoc* function gets a quasi-random name by default, (really it's the string "*self*" followed by the *PID*), or it can be passed a name, *e.g.* `strm2fnct foobar` names the *ad hoc* function `foobar()`;
- replaces every instance of `$0` with the *ad hoc* name, except that...
- these `timeout` commands in `wait-for-it.sh` require further
  edits:

  ```
  grep -n '^ *timeout' wait-for-it.sh 
  56:        timeout $BUSYTIMEFLAG $TIMEOUT $0 --quiet --child --host=$HOST --port=$PORT --timeout=$TIMEOUT &
  58:        timeout $BUSYTIMEFLAG $TIMEOUT $0 --child --host=$HOST --port=$PORT --timeout=$TIMEOUT &
  ```

  ...because `timeout` can't see shell
  functions, so the *ad hoc* function needs to be exported, and called by `bash -c`, and its arguments need to be quoted.  See what changes by running:

  ```
  diff wait-for-it.sh <( strm2fnct wait-for-it.sh < wait-for-it.sh )
  ```

Comment: well, close, but returns: `bash: --child: invalid option
Usage:  bash [GNU long option] [option] ...
 bash [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
 --debug
 --debugger
 --dump-po-strings
 --dump-strings
 --help
 --init-file
 --login
 --noediting
 --noprofile
 --norc
 --posix
 --protected
 --rcfile
 --rpm-requires
 --restricted
 --verbose
 --version
Shell options:
        -irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option          (invocation only)
        -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option bash: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for localhost:8181
`

Comment: @PeterButkovic, See revised answer for kludge.